# Runtime error when passing node colors for graph edges

Tags: python, networkx

When I run this example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

B=[[0,1],
  [2,4],
  [5,6],
  [3,7],
  [0,3]]
G = nx.Graph()   
for i in range(len(B)):
    G.add_edge((B[i][0]),(B[i][1]))
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True, node_color=[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]) 
plt.show()
```

It displays the graph. However, when I add more edges and node colors like so:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

B=[[0,1],
  [2,4],
  [5,6],
  [3,7],
  [0,3],
  [2,8],
  [7,11],
  [6,10],
  [3,12],
  [6,12]]   
G = nx.Graph()   
for i in range(len(B)):
    G.add_edge((B[i][0]),(B[i][1]))

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True, node_color=[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]) 
plt.show()
```

It raises this error.

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "0"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "0"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Node named 9 is missing in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The error didn't seem instructive to the nature of the problem here, but it's simply that you have 12 nodes and 13 node colours. Remove one of the items in `[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]` and the problem goes away.

Comment: So it's just a problem of " the number of nodes didn't fit the nodes colors' ",right? I thought too much...Thank you very much.